# Sorting csv data by longitude and latitude with Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm unsuccessfully trying to sort latitude and longitude data within a concatenated, formatted csv file. I keep attempting edits from stackoverflow syntax examples, (hope the syntax errors do not resurface), but now keep getting TypeError....argument 1 must have "write" method - which I do not fully understand.

I have attempted several edits and two different codes. I'm using python 2.7.13. I am specifically trying to 
1) Open the concatenated - 'combined' csv
2) sort by lat / long data from west to east
3) close the same file. (I'd prefer to not create a new file)

This csv will then be used for shapefile creation.

I'm super new at this and am not 100% sure if I should be doing this during the concatenate_csvs portion or the new sort_data portion. I'm not even sure what a write method is....google points me to Quote info. The documentation doesn't really state what the point of that is....so, I'm confused.

Feedback desperately needed and appreciated! I've spent a full 8 hrs on this :( :(

Kindly peek if my syntax is correct as I previously got a bunch of those errors.

And of course...I've checked out the documentation.

```
with open(combined, 'r+') as combined:

    header = reader.next()

    for val in combined:
        long = val[3]
        lat = val[4]

        long = sorted(coords, key = lambda x: x[3])
        lat = sorted(coords, key = lambda x: x[4])

        writer.writerow(combined, 'wb')
```

I have also tried this code....

```
for root, sub, files in os.walk(csv_dir):
    filenames = [os.path.join(root, filename) for filename in files
                if filename.endswith('intermediate.csv')]
    combined_path = os.path.join(root, 'combined.csv')
    with open(combined_path, 'w+') as combined:#orig

        writer = csv.writer(combined)#orig
        writer.writerow(header)#orig
        #new
        #for val in combined: 
            #val[3] = sorted(val[3], key=lambda x: x[3])
            #val[3] = val[3].sorted(key=lambda x: x[3])
        #NOTE - both of the above syntax generated the same error...assuming the syntax is synonymous. Still identifies as string data.

        write_files(filenames, combined)#orig
```

Comment: If you're getting an error message with your current code, then please provide the full error traceback along with a sample input and output for a [mcve]

Comment: Edit - I had to cut off some of my code since SO was not letting me post stating there was formatting error in my snippet.  I was getting the argument 1 must have a "write" method. I have added the quote info....

Comment: Edit - I had to cut off some of my code since SO was not letting me post stating there was formatting error in my snippet. (Once I lost the def statement it posted.)  I have added the quote info in the following line  writer = csv.writer(combined, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE) and this is the error - TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to write the file while you are reading it. That surely messes it up. If your data is not that large and fits into memory, you rather should load it and then sort it in memory. But for sorting the values, you need to convert them to numbers first.
I think the fastest way to do all this is using pandas. Like sketched below:

```
import pandas   

your_separator=','
df= pd.read_csv(file, dtype='str', sep=your_separator) # 1
df['sort_lat']=df[lat_col].astype('float64')   # 2
df['sort_long']=df[long_col].astype('float64') 

df.sort_values(['sort_lat', 'sort_long'], ascending=True, inplace=True) # 3
df.drop(['sort_lat', 'sort_long'], axis='columns', inplace=True) # 4
df.to_csv(file, sep=your_separator)
```

1) reads the file into a so called pandas DataFrame. The parameter dtype tells pandas, that it should interpret all fields as strings instead of doing automatic type conversions (just to make sure, we don't change the data unintendedly by rounding issues during type conversions).

2) creates two new columns in the dataframe with the binary form of the longtitude and the lattitude. You just need to replace lat_col and long_col with the actual names of the two fields in the original csv.

3) sorts the dataframe by the two fields and does reuse the existing dataframe (inplace) to safe memory.

4) removes the two auxillary columns we created, so we can save it, without them.

Ok, I know, maybe you don't like the idea of yet introducing another library into your solution, but pandas is really great for that kind of stuff and you can even use it to query or aggregate the data in a manner which is usually only possible in databases. So you probably need it later anyways.

Answer (score 0):

your attempts are full of conceptual errors. To open a csv file and sort rows according to 2 values (sorting as numerical requires `float` conversion) and write it back (with header) I would do this:

```
import csv,shutil

with open(combined, 'r') as fr, open(combined+".temp",'w',newline="") as fw:  # python 2: open(combined+".temp",'wb')
    reader = csv.reader(fr)
    writer = csv.writer(fw)
    header = reader.next()
    # write back the header or it's lost
    writer.writerow(header)
    # write the rest as sorted list of rows
    writer.writerows(sorted(list(reader), key=lambda x : (float(x[3]),float(x[4]))))
shutil.move(combined+".temp",combined)
```

notes:

- the lambda key function takes one row and extracts fields 3 and 4 (lat & long), yielding a composite key which puts all latitudes first, with tiebreaker on longitudes.
- sorting `reader` consumes it but it's faster to force input as a list of rows as `sorted` would do it anyway.
- you cannot open a text file in read/write. First read it, write it to another file, then move back if everything goes well, as shown above, using `shutil` to perform the move (which is a rename here since same filesystem is used)

Comment: I think you would have to convert the column values for long/lat to numeric types before you can safely sort them, otherwise I guess they would be compared as strings resulting in 200 being larger than 1000.

Comment: oh, sure. That's a stupid mistake!! thanks, fixed. I wanted to use slicing so much that I forgot this.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation - it made sense & helpful. Unfortunately I am using you're code above and am now getting a new error: TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function. Any ideas?

Comment: @CödingersCat: maybe you should consider switching to python3 as many libraries will stop their support for python2 soon.

Comment: Agreed on python 3 but at the moment it's not in my control :( The code worked eliminating the 'newline' (probably a 3 thing. I will learn more about the slicing in the future too. Thanks all!